# The system cannot find the file bin\gatherosstate.exe in windows 10 pro

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1607, windows-10-v1803

this file is not available in windows 10 pro version The system cannot find the file bin\gatherosstate.exe. Actually i upgraded from windows 8.1 to windows 10, is this error coming because of that, i used the tool available in Microsoft website for upgrade. Kindly provide solutions to get the file. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.